# how to check database value in the middleware laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I have a view which should be accessed only by the users who have "`role = interviewer`" in the database.I have created the middleware and registered it but it doesn't seem to work as expected. It allows all the users irrespective of their role stored in the DB.

Here is my middleware

```
class Interviewer
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user()->role == "interviewer"){
             return $next($request);
        }           
    }
}
```

I don't know if the approach is right i Have also tried

```
if($request->\Auth::user()->role == "interviewer")
```

This one also doesn't work. admin is the view it should be restricting if the user doesn't have the role interviewer. Here is my route

```
Route::get('/candidates', [
    'uses' => 'candidateController@showProfile',
    ])->middleware('auth','interviewer');
```

My route middlewares

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'interviewer'=> \App\Http\Middleware\Interviewer::class,
];
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something in your middleware if it needs to fail, in your case an error response.

```
namespace App\Core\Http\Middleware;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;

class Employee extends BaseMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next, $role = null)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        if (! ($user->authenticable instanceof \App\Core\Entities\User)) {
            return response([
                'title'  => 'You may not call this API as a non-employee.',
                'error'  => 'invalid_user_type'
            ], 401); // <-- See? I returned an error!
        }

        if ($role) {
            if (strtolower($user->authenticable->role->name) !== strtolower($role)) {
                return response([
                    'title'  => "You may not call this API as a \"{$user->authenticable->role->name}\".",
                    'error'  => 'unnecessary_permissions'
                ], 401); // And also here!
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using any package , i am doing this with default middleware of laravel

Comment: I am sorry. I have used package namespaces in the middleware, they may confuse you. However, the concept of how the middleware works remains the same. Try what I've shown you!

Answer (score 0):

In your middleware you always needs `return` to `next($request)`

```
class Interviewer { 
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) { 
        if($request->user()->role != "interviewer"){
             return back(); 
        } 
        return $next($request);
    } 
}
```

Also modify your `routes.php`. Middleware needs to be in an array:

```
Route::get('/candidates', [
    'uses' => 'candidateController@showProfile',
])->middleware(['auth','interviewer']);
```

Comment: I have edited Gayan's answer but it's pending for peer review. Basically, you need to add the middleware in an array like so: `middleware(['auth','interviewer']);` Do this in addition to what Gayan suggested

Comment: Thank you @Paras for the improvement